# Get the dbm in a toast

Tags: android, signal-strength, dbm

In my new project I need to show the dbm in a Toast. I have never before worked with the signal strength. I searched a lot on the internet but I did't find any good information. In my imagination it should be very easy, But I can't build something that works.
Could you help me please?

```
Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);             
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
           case R.id.start:
                Toast.makeText(this, "signal strength is " + this.signalDBM + "dBm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: try to put `getApplicationContext()` at the place of `this` ..

Answer (score 1):

**Wifi:**

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
int linkSpeed = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getRssi();
```

**Cellular:**

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
CellInfoGsm cellinfogsm = (CellInfoGsm)telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo().get(0);
CellSignalStrengthGsm cellSignalStrengthGsm = cellinfogsm.getCellSignalStrength();
int linkSpeed = cellSignalStrengthGsm.getDbm();
```

**In your** `Toast`:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "signal strength is " + linkSpeed + " dBm",
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```